# VirtueMart duplicate orders

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart, webshop

I'm currently developing a payment plugin for VirtueMart. I have never used it before. The goal is:

- When the user clicks to the confirm order button, he gets redirected to the bank interface (managed it, no work needed)
- He then gets redirected back to the webshop with an answer from the bank (also done)
- If the transaction is success, the order is stored as confirmed or if the transaction fails, the order is getting cancelled.

What I managed, is marked in the list above. For some reason, the order gets stored twice as pending, once when the user clicks the button, and once when the user gets redirected back to the shop. Also, if the transaction fails, the order is stored twice, also pending. I reused the standard payment plugin given with the VirtueMart aio package. All the above stuff is written in the `plgVmConfirmedOrder` function. I would post it here:

```
function plgVmConfirmedOrder ($cart, $order) {

    if (!($method = $this->getVmPluginMethod ($order['details']['BT']->virtuemart_paymentmethod_id))) {
        return NULL; // Another method was selected, do nothing
    }
    if (!$this->selectedThisElement ($method->payment_element)) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    VmConfig::loadJLang('com_virtuemart',true);
    VmConfig::loadJLang('com_virtuemart_orders', TRUE);

    if (!class_exists ('VirtueMartModelOrders')) {
        require(VMPATH_ADMIN . DS . 'models' . DS . 'orders.php');
    }

    $this->getPaymentCurrency($method);
    $currency_code_3 = shopFunctions::getCurrencyByID($method->payment_currency, 'currency_code_3');
    $email_currency = $this->getEmailCurrency($method);

    $totalInPaymentCurrency = vmPSPlugin::getAmountInCurrency($order['details']['BT']->order_total,$method->payment_currency);

    $dbValues['payment_name'] = $this->renderPluginName ($method) . '<br />' . $method->payment_info;
    $dbValues['order_number'] = $order['details']['BT']->order_number;
    $dbValues['virtuemart_paymentmethod_id'] = $order['details']['BT']->virtuemart_paymentmethod_id;
    $dbValues['cost_per_transaction'] = $method->cost_per_transaction;
    $dbValues['cost_percent_total'] = $method->cost_percent_total;
    $dbValues['payment_currency'] = $currency_code_3;
    $dbValues['email_currency'] = $email_currency;

    $dbValues['payment_order_total'] = $totalInPaymentCurrency['value'];
    $dbValues['tax_id'] = $method->tax_id;

    $payment_info='';
    if (!empty($method->payment_info)) {
        $lang = JFactory::getLanguage ();
        if ($lang->hasKey ($method->payment_info)) {
            $payment_info = vmText::_ ($method->payment_info);
        } else {
            $payment_info = $method->payment_info;
        }
    }
    if (!class_exists ('VirtueMartModelCurrency')) {
        require(VMPATH_ADMIN . DS . 'models' . DS . 'currency.php');
    }
    $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance ('', $order['details']['BT']->virtuemart_vendor_id);
            if(!array_key_exists("fizetesValasz", $_REQUEST)){
                $transaction_id = $this->getTransactionID();
                $_REQUEST['tranzakcioAzonosito'] = $transaction_id;
                $price = $cart->cartPrices['billTotal'];
                $_REQUEST['osszeg'] = round($price);
                $_REQUEST['devizanem'] = 'HUF';
                $_REQUEST['backURL'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/component/virtuemart/cart/confirm.html?Itemid=' . $_REQUEST['Itemid'];
                $_REQUEST['nyelvkod'] = 'hu';
                $dbValues['transaction_id'] = $transaction_id;
                //this is where I redirect to the bank interface
                process();
            }
            else{
                //this is where I get the data about transaction
                $transaction_datas = processDirectedToBackUrl(false);
                $status_code = $transaction_datas->getStatuszKod();
                $dbValues['otp_response'] = $status_code;
                $this->storePSPluginInternalData ($dbValues);
                $modelOrder = VmModel::getModel ('orders');
                switch ($status_code) {
                    case 'FELDOLGOZVA':
                        if($transaction_datas->isSuccessful()){
                            $message = 'Sikeres Tranzakció!';

                            $new_status = $this->getNewStatus($method);
                            $order['customer_notified'] = 1;
                            $order['comments'] = '';
                            $modelOrder->updateStatusForOneOrder ($order['details']['BT']->virtuemart_order_id, $order, TRUE);
                            $message = getMessageText(($transaction_datas->getPosValaszkod()));

                            $cart->emptyCart();
                            $html = $this->renderByLayout('post_payment_success', array(
                                'message' =>$message,
                                'order_number' =>$order['details']['BT']->order_number,
                                'order_pass' =>$order['details']['BT']->order_pass,
                                'payment_name' => $dbValues['payment_name'],
                                'displayTotalInPaymentCurrency' => round($totalInPaymentCurrency['display'])
                            )); 

                            vRequest::setVar ('html', $html);
                            return TRUE;
                        }
                        else{
                            $new_status = $method->status_cancelled;
                            $modelOrder->updateStatusForOneOrder($order['details']['BT']->virtuemart_order_id, $order, TRUE);
                            $message = 'Sajnos a bank visszautasította a tranzakciót.';
                            $html = $this->renderByLayout('post_payment_failure', array(
                                'message' => $message

                            ));
                            vRequest::setVar('html', $html);
                            return FALSE;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'VEVOOLDAL_VISSZAVONT':

                        return FALSE;
                        break;
                    case 'VEVOOLDAL_TIMEOUT':

                        return FALSE;
                        break;
                }


            }

            return FALSE;

}
```

Every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was the redirect url. There is an action called `plgVmOnPaymentResponseReceived()`. This is fired when a specific url is called. I only had to rewrite the `$_REQUEST` parameter for the redirection.